# Compare sort results by custom score

Tags: pre-post-comparison

I have one numeric score `S1` to (ascending) sort a dataset. Now I have developed another method that returns a numeric score `S2` that should sort the dataset in similar way. My question: with what methods can I evaluate the sorted results to compare performance of `S2` to the "ground truth" `S1`?

If S1 returns `ABCDEFG` and `S2` returns `ADEFGBC` , how can I compare the result of this permutation to the ground truth?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest metrics from information retrieval which are comparing ordered list of search results to assess the quality of a search engine. Try looking at MRR ([Mean reciprocal rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank)) or [Spearman rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) (but if not mistaken, the later needs a score associated to each ordered item).

Comment: Thanks, I'll into it. I also had the idea to simply count the number of required swaps to get the original list back. but Spearman rank makes sense, too. I would use the original sorted score vector and correlate it to the new score vector.